# How to extract text from all the elements in a webpage individually, using JSoup?

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

The problem here is, if I do:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url)
                        .timeout(30000)
                        .userAgent("Mozilla")
                        .followRedirects(true)
                        .get();
System.out.println(doc.select("body").text());
```

I get all the text in one chunk, and I don't want that.

Suppose I write a code like this:

```
String part="<div>
               Primary div
               <div>
                 Secondary div
               </div>
             </div>";
                Document doc = Jsoup.parse(part);
                Elements links = doc.select("div");
                for(Element e:links){
                    out.println(e.text());
                    System.out.println(e.text());
                }
```

The output is:

```
Primary div Secondary div
Secondary div
```

The inner div's text gets scraped twice.

I want that the scraping output should be like this:

```
Primary div
Secondary div
```

I want the text of each element to be unique excluding the text from the child elements.

How can this be achieved? The number of nested children can be more than just one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't getting two copies of `Secondary div`, you're outputting it twice: Once as part of the output of `Primary div`, then again on its own.

If you want just an element's **own** text and not the text of its child elements, use [`Element#ownText`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#ownText()).